# How to make a component draggable from any part except a Scroller inside the component

Tags: apache-flex

[image: Problem Description]

I have and Flex component that inside has a `profundidad` component that has a `Scroller` on a `DataGroup`

The component can be draged fine, but when I try to drag the scroll bar is dragging the whole component instead of dragging the scroll bar itself

**How can I make the component to be draggable from any other part besides the scroll bar and make the drag on the scroll bar to behave as expected (show more info above or below)
?**

The code for the main component is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         xmlns:c="Components.ComponentsMulticuenta.*"
         xmlns:c1="Components.*"
         xmlns:Front="Components.Front.*"
         mouseDown="initialPosition(event)" mouseUp="finalPosition(event)" 
         width="250" height.Start="94">

         private var isDragging:Boolean ;

            protected function initialPosition(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                isDragging = false ;

                if(event.localY <= 94)
                {
                    this.startDrag();

                    isDragging = true ;
                }
            }
            protected function finalPosition(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if(isDragging)
                {
                    this.stopDrag();
                    isDragging = false ;
                }
            }

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="Start"/>
        <s:State name="stateDown"/>
    </s:states>

    <s:BorderContainer borderStyle="solid"
                       top="0" width="100%" height="94" height.stateDown="210"
                       borderColor="#4F5548" horizontalCenter="0">
        <mx:Canvas id="fondo"  width="100%" height="100%">
            <c:profundidad includeIn="stateDown" id="prof" left="0" right="0" top="90" arrProff="{MarketInfoArray}"/>
        </mx:Canvas>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:Group>
```

The code for the `profundidad` component is

```
<mx:Canvas xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           width="248" height="100%">
           <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%" >

        <s:Scroller id="scroll" left="0" right="0" top="32" bottom="0" focusEnabled="false" hasFocusableChildren="true" >
            <s:DataGroup left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" dataProvider="{arrProff}"
                             itemRenderer="Components.ComponentsMulticuenta.DepthRender">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout gap="1"/>
            </s:layout>
            </s:DataGroup>      
        </s:Scroller>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the drag from the "close" button and also from the scroll bar, which in flex has the id `thumb` (for SliderThumb)

This is what I did

```
protected function initialPosition(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    isDragging = false ;

    if( event.target.hasOwnProperty("id") && (event.target.id != "close") && (event.target.id != "thumb"))
    {
        this.startDrag();

        isDragging = true ;

        parentApplication.showNemo(this) ;
    }
}
```